# Sharp or surprising?

Tags: pattern, english

### Sharp

- BR
- C
- CH
- DH
- H
- N
- PR
- V
- W

### Surprising

- BL
- CR
- FL
- GL
- KN
- L
- M
- SH
- SL
- SN
- ST
- THR
- T

### Both sharp and surprising

- B
- R
- S

---

## Question

Is **GR** sharp, surprising or both?  Why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sharp is

> anything followed by an "ow" sound when spelled with "ow":
>  brow, cow, chow, dhow, how, now, prow, vow, wow

Surprising is

> anything that is followed by an "oh" sound with "ow":
>  blow, crow, flow, glow, know, low, mow, show, slow, snow, stow, throw, tow

Some can be either:

> bow, row, sow

So GR is

> surprising, since "grow" is pronounced with "oh"

The terms:

> Sharp because "ow!" and surprising because "oh!" :)

Comment: That was quick!  Exactly correct.  (Including why "sharp" and "surprising" as terms)

Answer (score 8):

GR is

> Surprising

Reasoning

> For each sharp group, if we add 'ow' to the end, it produces a word which is pronounced with an 'ow' sound. On the other hand, adding 'ow' to the end of a surprising group produces a word with an 'o' sound.

Comment: Also very quick - and correct.